# Database Schema for Restaurant Table Merging and Unmerging

Tags: mysql

I need help to design a table for Restaurant Point of Sales System particularly in merging and unmerging restaurants table.

For example, i want to merge tables 1-3 as Table 1,

```
-Table 1
-Table 2
-Table 3
Table 4
Table 5
```

Then it would be something like this,

```
Table 1
  -Table 1
  -Table 2
  -Table 3
Table 4
Table 5
```

After a transaction the tables can be unmerge. Anyone who has a solution to this?

Comment: Create another entity `Order` that incorporates at least one table and has duration (starts at some time and ends at some time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what zerkms suggests, you will want a two-tiered system to support this approach. Link table information (server, order, timing, etc) to a **Seating**. **Seating** will have a one-to-many relationship with a **Table** relation.

When a guest is assigned to a single table, one **Table** will be linked to one **Seating**. If a group of guests is assigned to multiple tables, multiple **Table**s will be linked to a single **Seating**.

When a group of guests leaves, unlink their **Table**s from their **Seating**. To count unused tables, simply COUNT entries from **Table**.

```
- Seating 1
    - Table 1
- Seating 2
    - Table 2
    - Table 3
    - Table 4
```

*Note: **Table** entries will be static for the lifetime of the restaurant (unless more physical tables are added). **Seating** entries should be dynamically created and removed as necessary.*